# Azure Kuberenets Cluster: Could not find a ready tiller pod

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-nsg

I created an aks cluster using az aks create command with kubenet network and 2 nodes. Due to permissions issue in the AD account, the NSG had to be switched off before running the aks create command.  After the AKS cluster created successfully, the NSG was reapplied.

In order to check the health of the newly created cluster, when I run:

```
kubectl get nodes --all-namespaces;
```

there are no nodes returned. 
However, when I look into the azure portal and the corresponding vNet, there are 2vmss created using the ips within the subnet range. 
When I run:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces;
```

all pods are in pending state:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-xxxxdxxxxx-xxxxx               0/1     Pending   0          5h
kube-system   coredns-autoscaler-xxdxxxxxxxx-xxxx    0/1     Pending   0          5h
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-xxdxxxxxx-xxxxx   0/1     Pending   0          5h
kube-system   metrics-server-xxxxxxxdxx-xxxx         0/1     Pending   0          5h
kube-system   omsagent-rs-xxxxxxxxdx-xxxxx           0/1     Pending   0          5h
kube-system   tiller-deploy-xxxxxxxdxxx-xxxx         0/1     Pending   0          34m
kube-system   tunnelfront-xxxxxxxdx-xxxxx            0/1     Pending   0          5h
```

I then did a describe on the coredns pod:

```
kubectl describe pod coredns-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx -n kube-system
```

> Warning  FailedScheduling  2m40s (x2242 over 2d5h)  default-scheduler 
>   no nodes available to schedule pods

I need to deploy some containers using helm/tiller and when I run the installation commands I get the error

> Error: could not find a ready tiller pod

I know this is not directly to do with helm/tiller installation, the issue may be a bit more deeper.

I am new to Kubernetes, any thoughts on how to diagnose the issue will be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you create the tiller pod and init the helm?

Comment: I used: kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller

Comment: How do you init the helm and do you check if there is a running pod for the tiller in the namespace kube-system?

Answer (score 2):

if no nodes are returned from `kubectl get nodes` I'd suggest recreating the cluster, since if there are no nodes - no pods can ever run on this cluster. you might try and upgrade the cluster to a newer version of kubernetes (this would effectively redeploy the nodes), that might help.

Comment: Thank you, I will try recreating the cluster

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually deploy

```
kubectl logs --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy-xxxxxxxdxxx-xxxx
```

as stated in the below comments, there are no nodes and all the pods are in the pending state according to your logs, as recommended [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/394) you need to delete the cluster and recreate the cluster.

Comment: if you are using helm, go through the issue https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2064

Comment: Thanks for your response @Sajeetharan. I ran the kubectl logs command with my tiller-deploy pod and it returned empty result.  Regarding the helm issue link, I had already gone through all the options suggested in the link none of them worked.
When you say manually deploy, how do you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: as i see all of your pods are in pending state not only the tiller pod, as recommended you need to recreate the cluster and check the status once its created https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/394

Comment: Thanks , I will try recreating the cluster

Comment: how is this answer upvoted, when the command in question clearly wont work, because the pod is not there

Comment: I have stated to recreate the cluster. Maybe I need to add a bit of details in the first line (if pod exists ) and as i remember i posted the answer before you. so you might have seen